# Reactjs Expressjs end to end encryption

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, angularjs, express

I am not sure this question already been asked here. But I could not see such a question so far.

I have a RESTapi written in Express.js.
That RESTapi is connected to a React.js web app.
RESTapi is secured with JWT authentication tokens.

In the web app, we display thousands of product items with daily prices. Someone logging into the web app and viewing few product's prices is okay.
But what is not okay is someone automates the fetch all item's prices daily and store and analytics our pricing strategies.

Basically what I want is for someone trying to access the API using a tool like a postman or something it should be blocked. Only a web browser should be able to access the API. This can be achieved to some extend by blocking the user agents. We can block POSTMON user agents but how we block all the tools like POSTMON?

Even though If we block all the tools like that still browser's dev tools network tab they can see the response.

Is there a way to encrypt the response? So network tab will display something that the users can understand. But at the same time that response can be decrypted by React.

Hope my question is clear to all!

Any help!

Thanks in advance. =)

Comment: any answer to your question, i have almost the same problem

Answer (score 0):

> Basically what I want is for someone trying to access the API using a tool like a postman or something it should be blocked. Only a web browser should be able to access the API.

Can't be done.

> This can be achieved to some extend by blocking the user agents. We can block POSTMON user agents but how we block all the tools like POSTMON?

People can lie about the user-agent very easily.

> Even though If we block all the tools like that still browser's dev tools network tab they can see the response.

Yes. Browsers are designed to work for their user's benefits above the benefits of the owners of the websites they access.

> Is there a way to encrypt the response? So network tab will display something that the users can understand. But at the same time that response can be decrypted by React.

Not really. You'd have to give the decryption key to the browser, and if you give it to the browser then the user can access it.

> But what is not okay is someone automates the fetch all item's prices daily and store and analytics our pricing strategies.

Consider rate limiting instead.

---

Essentially, however, what you are trying to do is make information public without giving it to some people.

That's a contradiction and thus impossible.

Comment: @AyoubBenayache — If you have a new question, then [ask one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) (but your comment in its current state is about 8 different questions each of which is a combination of being too broad and opinionated for SO).

Comment: unfortunately yes, i'm looking for best practice of experts, SO will block me if i asked like this question. if you have  a direct link that explain all these staff, hope you share with me, and thank you in advance

Answer (score -1):

what you can do with express is to use CORS and allows only your website to reach the API.

check https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors

you gonna have something like

```
var express = require('express')
var cors = require('cors')
var app = express()
 
var corsOptions = {
  origin: 'http://example.com',
  optionsSuccessStatus: 200 // some legacy browsers (IE11, various SmartTVs) choke on 204
}
 
app.get('/products/:id', cors(corsOptions), function (req, res, next) {
  res.json({msg: 'This is CORS-enabled for only example.com.'})
})
```

but to use cors for that goal probably need to use a restriction based on user-agent, to make sure that all requests are coming from a browser and with cors header.

But still not a very efficient mechanism.

The other idea is to implement some sort of 'API KEY', generated by your client-side and validated on the backend. each request needs to have an 'API KEY' as param

Comment: No. CORS is used to **relax** the same origin policy in that browsers apply to cross origin requests. It can't make the rules stricter than default and it has no effect on non-browser clients (such as the example of Postman that was given in the question).

Answer (score -1):

You need to use CORS policy with HTTPS, if the policy is set correctly in CORS policy the request will be handled only if come from the UI App, otherwise, the app will reject the requests.
hope this code snippet will assist you

```
   const whitelist = ['http://www.example.com', 'https://www.example.com'];
    const corsOptions = {
      origin(origin, callback) {
        if (whitelist.indexOf(origin) !== -1 || !origin) {
          // !origin // allow requests with no origin (like mobile apps or curl requests)
          callback(null, true);
        } else {
          console.error(`Not allowed by CORS, Origin ${origin}`);
          callback(new Error('Not allowed by CORS'));
        }
      },
      exposedHeaders: 'Authorization',
    };
router.use(cors(corsOptions));
router.use('/api/auth', auth);
```

Comment: No. A CORS policy will only block web applications on other websites from accessing it directly from the client.